# Parsel is not able to access nested elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, lxml, parsel

I am working with [Parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Unfortunately, I am not able to parse `<a>` tag, which is child of another `<a>` tag (I know, that `<a>` inside `<a>` isn't `HTML` standard). How can I handle this situation via `Parsel` ? I have already solved this problem using `Beautiful Soup` + `html.parser` as a backend (`Beatufiul Soup` + `lxml` does not work as well).

```py
from parsel import Selector

html_text = '''
<html>
    <head>
    <base href='http://example.com/' />
    <title>Example website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#">
        <a id="test" href='image1.html'>Name: My image 1 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image3.html'>Name: My image 3 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image4.html'>Name: My image 4 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /></a>
    </a>
    </body>
    </html>
'''

selector = Selector(text=html_text)
print(selector.xpath('//a/a')) # `<class 'parsel.selector.SelectorList'>` is an empty...
```

If I put `<a>` inside `<div>` everything works fine. There is an example below:

```py
from parsel import Selector

html_text = '''
<html>
    <head>
    <base href='http://example.com/' />
    <title>Example website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <a id="test" href='image1.html'>Name: My image 1 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image3.html'>Name: My image 3 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image4.html'>Name: My image 4 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /></a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
'''

selector = Selector(text=html_text)
print(selector.xpath('//div/a')) # <class 'parsel.selector.SelectorList'> is not empty...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`lxml.html`](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/618ad9ff531ede92c27ef183c4da3332ec3cbc39/parsel/selector.py#L71) parser that `Parsel` uses "fixes" the HTML code and puts the inner `<a>` outside. Try to specify `type="xml"` when instantiating the `Selector`:

```py
from parsel import Selector

html_text = """
<html>
    <head>
    <base href='http://example.com/' />
    <title>Example website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="#">
        <a id="test" href='image1.html'>Name: My image 1 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image2.html'>Name: My image 2 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image3.html'>Name: My image 3 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image4.html'>Name: My image 4 <br /></a>
        <a id="test" href='image5.html'>Name: My image 5 <br /></a>
    </a>
    </body>
    </html>
"""

selector = Selector(text=html_text, type="xml")
# print how the Parsel parses the document:
# print(selector.getall()[0])
print(selector.xpath("//a/a"))
```

Prints:

```py
[
 <Selector query='//a/a' data='<a id="test" href="image1.html">Name:...'>,
 <Selector query='//a/a' data='<a id="test" href="image2.html">Name:...'>,
 <Selector query='//a/a' data='<a id="test" href="image3.html">Name:...'>,
 <Selector query='//a/a' data='<a id="test" href="image4.html">Name:...'>,
 <Selector query='//a/a' data='<a id="test" href="image5.html">Name:...'>
]
```

Comment: Do you recommend to use `type="xml"` when working with `HTML` documents ? Is it safer ?

Comment: @ifdef14 It depends on the site. I don't use Parsel but bs4. Some sites have malformed markup so only `html5lib` helps for other `html.parser` is better. You can run `bs4.diagnose.diagnose(html_text)` to see how various parsers parse the HTML.

Comment: @ifdef14 severely broken HTML is rare in my experience, also in many cases you can just write selectors for the "fixed" DOM, if that's easier and makes sense.